# Pixelated font as on Texas Instruments calculators

Tags: fonts, pdftex, pixelated

For pedagogical reasons, I would like to build one environment to display something like the screen of one Texas Instruments calculator.

What I'm looking for is a way to produce, via pdflatex, one pixelated font on Windows, Linux and also Mac OS.

Is it possible?

Comment: Well, as `xelatex`/`lualatex` with `fontspec` allow you to use TrueType fonts, you need only find a [suitable](http://www.fontspace.com/style-7/digital-7) [font](http://www.fontspace.com/lcd-solid/lcd-solid), I guess.

Comment: The problem is that I can't use for the moment...

Comment: If you have some free time, you can make one yourself (since such font does not contain too much characters, and their shapes are "easy", this is probably less work than it might seem, and probably some fun, too ;) ) and draw it in `tikz`.  In such a case, `pdf(la)tex` is enough.
That said, a ready-made font is probably a better idea anyway.

Comment: If you're bound to using *e.g.*, `pdflatex`, you should specify that in your question.

Comment: I did a general tidy-edit on your post, but I also removed the dollar symbol in the interests of keeping this platform agnostic.

Comment: I'm a Mac conquered user...

Comment: I wonder how much effort has been devoted in the past to achieve the **opposite** effect... :)

Comment: You're right ! :-) But for pupils, this kind of back to the past feature is very efficient.

Comment: There is [this font](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/necker/) from the Font Catalogue, but while it is available on CTAN, it isn't in either TeXlive or MikTeX. Perhaps not exactly what you're after though.

Comment: Consider using a regular monospace font instead. Frame it, maybe use a [slashed zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slashed_zero) variant, and you get a realistic calculator screen effect. A pixel font will just make the reading harder and stress the reader's eyes.

Comment: You can capture the screen using [TiLP](http://lpg.ticalc.org/prj_tilp/)

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70532/1871

Answer (score 5):

I am absolutely no expert on this, but couldn't you use [this howto on using ttf fonts in pdftex](http://www.radamir.com/tex/ttf-tex.htm), and this [pixelated font](http://www.dafont.com/pixelated.font) to achieve your goal?

Update: There is even a site over at Ti which gives you the [fonts for the keys](http://education.ti.com/educationportal/sites/US/sectionHome/download.html) of all the Ti calculators, if you need to explain in the text which keys are to be pressed.

Comment: This has all the ingredients of a good solution, but as it stands it's more of a comment. You should complete it...

Comment: There's also a pixelated font that includes the math characters that would be needed: http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/83lgfont

Comment: @Arne : the problem is that I would like to find an easy way to do that so as to share my environment with other users...

Comment: @projetmbc Package up the LaTeX file and the font in a compressed (zip, tar.gz, 7z, tar.bz) archive and send that out?