# Typesetting keys with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am using a little TikZ Code to typeset Calculator keys, which works pretty well in general. I only have one problem: when I type just single lines I would like to have the corresponding box as big as the ones with two parts in it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[]{amsmath}
\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,shadows}

\tikzstyle{abstract}=[rectangle, draw=black, rounded corners, fill=gray!30,drop shadow, text centered,  text=black, text width=8mm]
\tikzstyle{fkey}=[rectangle, draw=black, rounded corners, fill=orange,drop shadow, text centered,  text=black, text width=8mm]
\tikzstyle{gkey}=[rectangle, draw=black, rounded corners, fill=blue!40,drop shadow, text centered,  text=black, text width=8mm]

\newcommand{\mykey}[2]{%
\begin{tikzpicture} \node (Item) [abstract, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2]{\textbf{\scriptsize{#1}} \nodepart{second}\textbf{\tiny{#2}}};%
\end{tikzpicture}}

\newcommand{\myfkey}{%
\begin{tikzpicture} \node (Item) [fkey, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2]{\textbf{\footnotesize{f}} \nodepart{second}};%
\end{tikzpicture}}

\newcommand{\mygkey}{%
\begin{tikzpicture} \node (Item) [gkey, rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2]{\textbf{\footnotesize{g}} \nodepart{second}};%
\end{tikzpicture}}

\newcommand{\mynumberkey}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture} \node (Item) [abstract]{\textbf{#1}};%
\end{tikzpicture}}


\begin{document}


 \mykey{n}{$12x$}

 \mykey{SST}{$\Delta \text{DYS}$}

 \myfkey

 \mygkey

 \mykey{Enter}{=}

\mynumberkey{3}

\end{document}
```

[image: calculator keys]

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but do you know that you can use ttf fonts for calculators? Like [Texas](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37550/1952) or [HP](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Other-HP-Consumer-Products-and/HP-12c-keyboard-font/td-p/295767)

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220281/draw-calculator-keys-with-latex

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can simply add, when you define the styles, `minimum height=...`.

For example:

```
\tikzset{abstract/.style={rectangle, 
       draw=black,
       rounded corners,
       fill=gray!30,
       drop shadow,
       text centered,
       text=black,
       text width=8mm,
       minimum height=0.75cm,
   }
}
\tikzstyle{fkey/.style={rectangle, 
       draw=black,
       rounded corners,
       fill=orange,
       drop shadow,
       text centered,
       text=black, 
       text width=8mm,
       minimum height=0.75cm,
  }
}
\tikzstyle{gkey/.style={rectangle, 
      draw=black,
      rounded corners,
      fill=blue!40,
      drop shadow,
      text centered,
      text=black, 
      text width=8mm,
      minimum height=0.75cm,
   }
}
```

in your preamble will lead to:

[image]