# Draw calculator keys with LaTeX?

Tags: fonts, keyboard

How can you typeset keys to get the impression of a Calculator?

Remark: This question is a split-of [Keyboard Font for LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5226/keyboard-font-for-latex)

Comment: In case you also need to draw a screen: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/70532/1871

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There are packages for it:

- http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tipfr
- https://ctan.org/pkg/graph35 Draw keys and screen items of several Casio calculators

## tipfr

Example from the doc:

[image]

A small example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,english]{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{babel} 
\usepackage{tipfr} 

\begin{document}

Push 
\Touche[style=number, principal=1]
\Touche[style=operation, principal=+]
\Touche[style=number, principal=2]
\Touche[style=function,principal={=},]
and you get the result 3.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Some examples for the \Touche-macro:
[image]

## [graph35](https://ctan.org/pkg/graph35) - Casio calculators

Actually  (2018-03-24) one model is available: graph35+.

Comment: I like it! But why not give a MWE for people to copy and paste the code? The documentation had just snippets of code.

Comment: I downloaded the files from CTAN, put the style file in with the tex file but it wouldn't compile. The error message was: "newtxtt.sty not found". I googled and found a copy on the internet. Put that in the same file and again it wouldn't compile: "I do not know the /tcb/color key and I'm going to ignore it". The problem is line 14. Any idea how to continue?

Comment: @DJP newtxtt can be found on CTAN at http://www.ctan.org/pkg/newtxtt. With version 1.03 and 1.051 (the actual one) I get no error. I look for a MWE - actually I found a bug (?) in tipfr.sty with babel and `\shorthandon{;}` (line 422 + 494) - I kep you informed.

Comment: @DJP have you updated LaTeX on your computer?  For example, `newtxtt` is a fairly new addition.

Comment: @knut I do have the updated newtxtt.sty file but I still can't compile your MWE. I get "./tipfr.sty:422: Package babel Error: I cannot switch `;' on or off--not a shorthand." and later: "l.422 \shorthandon{;}". This sounds like the bug(?) you mention above.

Comment: @knut I'm using TeXLive 2013. Perhaps that's the problem.

Comment: @DJP: I was succesful with pdflatex. With luaLaTeX I get the error.

Comment: @knut I'm getting the error with pdfTeX (TeXLive2013/Debian)

Answer (score 3):

`\shorthandon{}` and `\shorthandoff{}` do not make sense for French with LuaTeX or XeTeX as high punctuation characters (:;!?) are no longer made active with these engines.

I would suggest dropping the two commands `\shorthandon{;}` and `\shorthandoff{;}` in `tipfr.sty` and adding `babel` to the options of `\usetikzlibrary{...}` on line 10, this should take care of `;` characters when they happen to be active (in French with TeX or pdfTeX engines).

Comment: I made those changes and it's working for me! This will be a useful package to have. Thanks! +1.

Comment: This should be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: +1 - although it should be a comment - but it really solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

I can't write a comment because I haven't enough reputation so I use the answer box.
You can draw calculator's keys with the `tipfr` package. There is a update (see http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tipfr) : with the help of the previous answer, the problem you met is fixed.

The "principal" option can now be called with the "enter" style.
For example : `\Touche[style=enter,principal={=}]` or `\Touche[style=enter,principal={EXE}]`

I added a starred version to `\Calculatrice` to draw a small calculator (see an example at the end of documentation)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you elaborate on your answer it's more than a comment ;-)

Comment: +1 for the package and the quick solution of the problem. And for the info, why it's an answer and no comment ;)

Answer (score 2):

Now it exists a new package to draw keys of a scientific calculator. I used that calculator when I teached at Junior High School.

ticollege.sty : https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ticollege