# How can you typeset keys to get the impression of a Calculator?

Tags: calculations

How can you typeset keys to get the impression of a Ti-84 Calculator?
The only responses I see are for French calculators.

Comment: The `tipfr` package is French, but it can actually display arbitrary text for the keys, also English, using the `principal` option. See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/220281/draw-calculator-keys-with-latex.

Comment: Nowadays nobody is using these any more. You might want to draw a [smartphone](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/479893/121799) instead. ;-) Some [can be drawn very easily](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479840/a-collection-of-the-actual-smartphones#comment1212593_479840). ;-)

Comment: @marmot - I guess I am nobody.  I would sooner post my SS number on the internet than own a smart phone.