# Calculator style base 10 notation in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, fonts

What is the best way to write something like 6.22E-21 in LaTeX, given that I don't want the numerals to be \tt, I do want the E to be small, and I may want the exponent to be negative (without the huge LaTeX minus sign)?

I'm sure this is a duplicate of another question that I just can't find.

Example here: [image]

Comment: The description is not letting me visualise what you want.(But, may be, I am the only one.) Perhaps, why not give us a sample to think about?

Comment: @KannappanSampath I tried, it wouldn't let me post images. I've added a link.

Comment: You could try `$6.22\mbox{\textsc{e}}-21$`. I'm assuming this number will be typeset on math mode, right? If you don't want a (typographically correct) math minus sign but a simple dash, be sure to include it in the argument of the `\mbox` command.

Comment: @Mico `$6.22\mbox{\sc{e}-}21$` is definitely the correct answer, it looks exactly how I'd like it to! You should post that so I can checkmark it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For a one-off implementation of your typesetting needs, you could try

```
6.22\mbox{\sc{e}-}21
```

This will work in both text and math mode. If you use the `amsmath` package, you should type

```
6.22\text{\sc{e}-}21
```

as this is slightly more general than the first solution. Specifically, it'll work better if the expression ever occurs in scriptstyle (first-level sub- and superscripts) or scriptscriptstyle (second-level sub- and superscripts) material.

Conversely, if you have a lot of numbers that you wish to typeset in this way, you should implement a solution along the lines provided in @AlfC's answer. Otherwise, sooner or later some inconsistencies in the way you typeset these numbers will creep in.

Answer (score 36):

By far the most elegant way to do it is using the `siunitx` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-exponent-marker=\textsc{e}}
\begin{document}
\num{6.02e23}
\end{document}
```

[image: calculator style]

**EDIT 1:** If you want a short minus sign, a not so elegant solution (but still within `siunitx`) is to replace this more complicated `sisetup` line:

```
\sisetup{output-exponent-marker=\textsc{e}, bracket-negative-numbers, open-bracket={\text{-}}, close-bracket={}}
```

[image: short minus]

This will in general affect also negative numbers (even without exponents) used within `\num`. For other hacks regarding the minus sign look at this question [Making a shorter minus](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6058/making-a-shorter-minus) or [Typesetting of negative versus minus?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4756/typesetting-of-negative-versus-minus?rq=1), no answer on this was really satisfactory to me.

**EDIT 2 (2014):** If you make XeLaTeX use [Écran Font](http://www.dafont.com/ecran-monochrome.font?text=6.02ᴇ-23%20e) (for example) and some TikZ shadows you can give it a complete look

[image: calc]

(note the use of the unicode chacaracter "ᴇ", I needed to use this particular font because it was the only one with this character)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[ExternalLocation={./}]{ecran-monochrome---monochrome-display.ttf} % Écran Monochrome
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\calcshadow[1]{
\tikz[baseline]{
    \node[black!50!white] at (0.02,-0.02) {\num[output-exponent-marker=\text{ᴇ}, output-decimal-marker=\text{.}, bracket-negative-numbers, open-bracket={\text{-}}, close-bracket={}]{#1}};
    \node[] at (0.,0.) {\num[output-exponent-marker=\text{ᴇ}, output-decimal-marker=\text{.}, bracket-negative-numbers, open-bracket={\text{-}}, close-bracket={}]{#1}};
}
}
\begin{document}
\colorbox{gray!70}{
\calcshadow{6.02e-23}
}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT 3**: Alternative style using unicode block character "█":

[image: blockcalc]

```
...
\newcommand\calcshadow[1]{
\tikz[baseline]{
    \node[black!20!white] at (0.,0.) {████████};
    \node[black!80!white,opacity=0.5] at (0.02,-0.02) {\num[output-exponent-marker=\text{ᴇ}, output-decimal-marker=\text{.}, bracket-negative-numbers, open-bracket={\text{-}}, close-bracket={}]{#1}};
    \node[] at (0.,0.) {\num[output-exponent-marker=\text{ᴇ}, output-decimal-marker=\text{.}, bracket-negative-numbers, open-bracket={\text{-}}, close-bracket={}]{#1}};
}
}
...
```

Comment: That looks good, how does it handle minus signs in the exponent? One problem (that I didn't put in my question): I'm using matplotlib, so extra packages probably aren't an option.

Comment: @alfC You'll get a minus sign with `siunitx`: the question seems to be after what you see with a calculator, which is much more hyphen-like.

Comment: See my edit. If you can't load external packages then use another solution, like Fabio's or Mico's.

Comment: If you go into TikZ pgfmath already offers pretty printing options.

Comment: Another suggestion. Instead of the hyphen, you could make a [rounded rule](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161297/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-mathrule-rounded-endcaps): exactly like a minus, but with the length and width you desire. I think it will look much better than that hyphen.

Comment: @Manuel, thanks for the suggestion. I was looking for that before. However is that `mathrule` something standard or I need to incorporate all the code in the postings? If so, I prefer to hack/scale/raise math `$-$` insteadm, such as ${}^-$, like described in my answer here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/152323/1871.

These are other questions that can benefit from this: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4756/typesetting-of-negative-versus-minus?lq=1  http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6058/making-a-shorter-minus?lq=1

Comment: You don't need to include it, my intention was just to point that out for future readers. However, yes, there are other questions that can benefit from that ;)

Answer (score 6):

It is working in LaTeX, http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lcd .

[image]

For 10,

```
\DefineLCDchar{10}{00000000000000010111101011010110111}
```

For small caps shape {E},

```
\DefineLCDchar{12}{00000000000111101000011100100001111}
```

It may be necessary, http://latexcolor.com/

Thanks a lot, Mike Kaufmann.

Comment: Well it has been a while, but that is pretty spiffy :)

Answer (score 3):

You could try this code:

```
% this has to go in the preamble of the document.
\DeclareMathSymbol{\minus}{\mathord}{operators}{"2D} % unary minus
\newcommand{\scinot}[2]{#1\,\textrm{\scriptsize E}{#2}} % scientific notation
$\scinot{10}{\minus2}$
```