# How to make a fixed height-width box with custom padding

Tags: boxes, width, height

I am new to latex, I am trying to include output of TI84 calculator in my document.

It is supposed to look like this:

[image: actual TI 84]

Following is what I am able to make.

[image: my texas calculator]

My output's height and width arrange itself, I want fixed height/width, with custom padding and text wrapping around inside the box. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

My code is

```
{\scriptsize
\setmainfont{Texas Instruments TI-84 series}
\tabulinesep=0.05 in
\begin{tabu} to 1 in {|c |}
\hline
normalcdf(-1.5,2)\\
\hfill .9104427093
\\\hline
\end{tabu}
}
```

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79444/mimic-a-calculator-screen

Comment: It would be more useful if MWE were given so others can know, for example, what other packages need to be loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\vbox to...` primitive construction is the answer to your question. You can try the following code:

```
\def\tifont{\setmainfont{Texas Instruments TI-84 series}}
\setbox0=\hbox{\tifont 12345678901234567\kern2pt}\edef\tiwidth{\wd0}
\def\ticalc#1{\hbox{\vrule\vbox to2cm{\hrule\kern1pt
   \def\l##1|{\hbox to\tiwidth{\kern1pt##1\kern1pt\hss}}\tifont #1\vss\hrule}\vrule}}

\ticalc{
\l normalcdf(-1.5,2)|
\l\hfill .9104427093|
}
```

**Edit:** My second version of the macro `\ticalc` implements the auto-wrapping. The width of the box has to be set by setbox. See the line with `\setbox0` where 16 characters is supposed. The text with more length than this dimension is wrapped. The wrapping is possible between each pair of characters.

The optional `\result` followed by text can be included in the parameter of the `\ticalc` macro. Such text is printed at next line aligned to right.

```
\def\titext{\hsize=\tiwidth \leftskip=1pt\rightskip=1pt plus1fil \tifont \noindent \titextA}
\def\titextA{\futurelet\next\titextB}
\def\titextB{\ifx\next\result \else \null\next \penalty0 \expandafter\titextC \fi}
\def\titextC{\afterassignment\titextA \let\next= }

\newfontfamily\tifont{Texas Instruments TI-84 series}
\setbox0=\hbox{\tifont 1234567890123456\kern2pt}\edef\tiwidth{\wd0}
\def\ticalc#1{\hbox{\vrule\vbox to2cm{\hrule\kern1pt\titext#1\result\relax\vss\hrule}\vrule}}
\def\result#1\relax{\par\let\result=\relax \hbox to\tiwidth{\hss#1\kern1pt}}

\ticalc{normalcdf(-1.5,2)\result .9104427093}

\ticalc{abcdefghijklmnopqrsyuyu}
```

Comment: @VarunSeth Do you mean wrapping between letters inside words?

Comment: `\newfontfamily\tifont{Texas Instruments TI-84 series}` is better than resetting the main font.

Comment: @egreg Thanks, I've added the code by your advice. I put my original line blind, because I have no such font and I didn't load the font package used by OP, because it is LaTeX specific package.

Comment: It would be nice to have packages indicated that are necessary to get this example to compile.

Comment: @A.Ellett Sorry, I can't serve, because I don't know what packages were used by OP. I guess that it is some from LaTeX and that XeTeX or LuaTeX were used, but I don't know. Anyway, the example cannot be compilable if the special font isn't present. I hope that if somebody needs to try this example then he/she is able to think and he/she does `\let\tifont=\tt` for example.

Answer (score 6):

The following solution borrows some code from this [great answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153692/27635) of egreg:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewEnviron{terminal}
 {
  \raggedright\varun_zerohyphen:V \BODY
 }

\seq_new:N \l_varun_body_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \varun_zerohyphen:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_varun_body_seq { ~ } { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_varun_body_seq { \varun_printword:n { ##1 } }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \varun_zerohyphen:n { V}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \varun_printword:n #1
 {
  \tl_map_inline:nn { #1 } { ##1 \penalty0 \scan_stop: }
  \c_space_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

This defines a new environment `terminal` that automatically wraps the text inside the box.

The box is made through a `minipage` inside a `tcolorbox` environment.

This is the full code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\TIfont{Texas Instruments TI-84 series}

% Start ----------- Code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153692

\usepackage{xparse,environ}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewEnviron{terminal}
 {
  \raggedright\varun_zerohyphen:V \BODY
 }

\seq_new:N \l_varun_body_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \varun_zerohyphen:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_varun_body_seq { ~ } { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_varun_body_seq { \varun_printword:n { ##1 } }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \varun_zerohyphen:n { V}

\cs_new_protected:Npn \varun_printword:n #1
 {
  \tl_map_inline:nn { #1 } { ##1 \penalty0 \scan_stop: }
  \c_space_tl
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

% End ----------- Code from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153692


\begin{document}

{\scriptsize
\TIfont
\begin{tcolorbox}[%
      arc=0pt,
      outer arc=0pt,
      boxsep=1pt,
      top=0mm,
      bottom=10mm,
      left=0mm,
      right=0mm,
      boxrule=0.3pt,
      colback=white,
      colframe=black,
      hbox
]
\begin{minipage}{1.14in}
\begin{terminal}
normalcdf(-1.5,2)\par
\hfill .9104427093\par
$\blacksquare$\par
\end{terminal}
\end{minipage}
\end{tcolorbox}
}

\end{document}
```

and this is the result:

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't reset the main font, but rather define a new font family: add `\newfontfamily\TI{...}` to the preamble and issue `\TI` in the code for `terminal`.

Answer (score 4):

A variant of karlkoeller's answer, where the width, height, padding and alignment of the box are customizable. Alignment refers to the vertical alignment of the box with respect to the surrounding material.

The setup expects a monospaced font is used in the box; I used “DejaVu Sans Mono” as I don't have the “Texas Instruments TI-84 series” font; just change the font in the `\newfontfamily` line.

Default values:

- height: 8 (lines)
- width: 16 (characters)
- padding: 1pt
- align: c

Possible values for `align` are `c`, `t` and `b`.

You can set the values with a key-value interface in the optional argument to `terminal` as shown.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xparse,environ}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newfontfamily\TI{DejaVu Sans Mono} % or whatever

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewEnviron{terminal}[1][]
 {
  \scriptsize\TI
  \keys_set:nn { varun/display } { width=16 , #1 }
  \fbox
   {
    \parbox
     [\l_varun_align_tl]                 % outer alignment
     [\l_varun_height_int \baselineskip] % height
     [t]                                 % inner alignment
     {\l_varun_width_dim}                % width
     {
      \raggedright % don't try filling up lines
      \varun_zerohyphen:V \BODY
     }
   }
 }

\seq_new:N \l_varun_body_seq
\dim_new:N \l_varun_width_dim

\cs_new_protected:Npn \varun_zerohyphen:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_varun_body_seq { ~ } { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_varun_body_seq { \varun_printword:n { ##1 } }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \varun_zerohyphen:n { V }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \varun_printword:n #1
 {
  \tl_map_inline:nn { #1 } { ##1 \penalty\c_zero }
  \c_space_tl
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \__varun_set_width:n #1
 {
  \hbox_set:Nn \l_tmpa_box { \prg_replicate:nn { #1 } { A } }
  \dim_set_eq:NN \l_varun_width_dim \box_wd:N \l_tmpa_box
 }

\keys_define:nn { varun/display }
 {
  width   .code:n    = \__varun_set_width:n { #1 },
  padding .code:n    = \dim_set:Nn \fboxsep { #1 },
  padding .initial:n = 1pt,
  height  .int_set:N = \l_varun_height_int,
  height  .initial:n = 8,
  align   .tl_set:N  = \l_varun_align_tl,
  align   .initial:n = c,
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{terminal}
normalcdf(-1.5,2)\\
\hfill .9104427093\\
1\\
2\\
3\\
4\\
▪
\end{terminal}\qquad
\begin{terminal}[width=20]
normalcdf(-1.5,2)\\
\hfill .9104427093\\
▪
\end{terminal}

\bigskip

\begin{terminal}[align=t]
normalcdf(-1.5,2)\\
\hfill .9104427093\\
▪
\end{terminal}\qquad
\begin{terminal}[align=t,height=4]
normalcdf(-1.5,2)\\
\hfill .9104427093\\
▪
\end{terminal}\qquad
\begin{terminal}[align=t,height=4,padding=6pt]
normalcdf(-1.5,2)\\
\hfill .9104427093\\
▪
\end{terminal}


\end{document}
```

Instead of `\fbox` one could use the fancier methods provided by `tcolorbox`.

[image]

Comment: Why the use of `\c_space_tl` in the definition of `\varun_printword:n`?  Things seem to work with or without it.

Comment: @A.Ellett Probably it was necessary for the application made in http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153692/27635 *If it ain't broken, don't fix it!*

Comment: Thanks for pointing to that example.  I am now quite enlightened.  :)

Comment: +1 for the customizable environment. P.S. I couldn't upvote the answer where I borrowed your code because I did it already time ago ;-)