# siunitx and engineering 'E' notation

Tags: formatting, siunitx

Is it possible to use the [`siunitx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx) package to typeset numbers with the "E" notation so that the output might look like

```
1E3
```

instead of

```
1 x 10^3
```

Comment: For alternatives, look here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70528/calculator-style-base-10-notation-in-latex

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, see p. 29 in the manual:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{output-exponent-marker=\ensuremath{\mathrm{E}}}

\begin{document}
\num{1e3}

\SI{2.3e5}{m}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I looked in the manual and on this site and couldn't find it. I realize now I was in the SIunits manual, not the siunitx manual.