# Pgfplot how to make scientific number format with "e" exponent style

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

The normal scientific coordinate is something like `10^2`, how do I change it to `1e+2` style ?

### For example:

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
scaled ticks=false,
y tick label style={/pgf/number format/sci},
ymin=1, ymax=5000,
]
\addplot {pow(x, x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It should be 1e+3, 2e+3 and so forth.

Comment: Don't think this can handle variables like `x` in the notation (unless you mean it as a placeholder for an actual number), but it is related, nonetheless: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110388/siunitx-and-engineering-e-notation

Comment: Whoever voted to close: If this is a duplicate, it's *not* of that question. This question has nothing to do with `siunitx`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes no it's just a number, not a variable. And yes, this has nothing to do with siunitx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is actually described in the manual for pgf/TikZ. See section 92.1 *Changing display styles* (for v3.0.1a, dated August 29, 2015).

You're almost there in fact, just change the number formatting option for the `yticklabel`s to `/pgf/number format/.cd,sci,sci e`. If you want a capital e, use `sci E` instead.

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
scaled ticks=false,
y tick label style={/pgf/number format/.cd,sci,sci e},
ymin=1, ymax=5000,
]
\addplot {pow(x, x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Old answer

Is this what you were after?

```
\documentclass[border=4mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{semilogyaxis}[
log number format basis/.code 2 args={e${\pgfmathprintnumber[showpos=true]{#2}}$}
]
\addplot {exp(x)};
\end{semilogyaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Seems like what I want, but the number in front of e is wrong, for example: `1 * 10^2` becomes just `e+2`, is there anyway to make it like `1e+2` ? And is there anyway for it to work with normal axis instead of semilog ?

Comment: @iKid Could you add a minimal example of what you have to your question? I.e. something like the code in my answer, only showing the type of values you want to modify. (Would make the question much clearer.)

Comment: I added the example

Comment: awesome, I'm looking for this option I don't know why I have missed it