# Is there such a thing as a `\mathrule`? (rounded endcaps)

Tags: symbols

When I am creating hybrid math glyphs, I will find myself often times stacking `\rule`s about the place.  But if you look at a collection of CM math symbols (top row), and compare it to a `\rule` (2nd row)

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\noindent$+ - = \subset \geq \ni$\\$\rule{2ex}{.3pt}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

you will find that strokes comprising the math glyphs exhibit rounded ends, whereas a `rule` has flattened ends.  At typical size, the difference may be insignificant, but for scaled-up glyphs, it is noticeable.

Is there a version of a `\rule`, which I jokingly here called `\mathrule`, that will provide the functionality (even the syntax) of a `\rule`, but with rounded endcaps?  (preferably not with `tikz`, but something more native).

I've considered stretching and squeezing, for example, a minus sign, but that will result in spherical end caps becoming elliptical, especially when the distortion is large.

---

I was going to put this attempt up to get the ball rolling, but Herbert beat me to it.  I'll still leave it here as food for thought.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{verbatimbox}
\newsavebox\clippedbullet
\sbox{\clippedbullet}{\addvbuffer[.0pt -.55pt]{$\bullet$}}
\def\CB{\usebox{\clippedbullet}}
\newcommand\mathrule[3][0pt]{%
\raisebox{#1}{\scaleleftright{\kern-.8pt\CB\kern-2.5pt}%
  {\rule{#2-#3}{#3}}{\kern-2.4pt\CB\kern+.0pt}}%
}
\begin{document}
\noindent\mathrule[2pt]{2ex}{.5pt} \mathrule{3ex}{1pt} \mathrule[-1pt]{2ex}{2pt}\\
\rule[2pt]{2ex}{.5pt} \rule{3ex}{1pt} \rule[-1pt]{2ex}{2pt}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: No, there isn't. Longer arrows are built by repeating minus signs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
\pdfcompresslevel=0 %%% to see how it works in the pdf code
\pdfcompresslevel=0
\documentclass{article}
\parindent=0pt
\makeatletter
\def\mathrule#1#2{%
  \@tempdima=\dimexpr#1-0.5#2
  \@tempdimb=#2
  \@tempdimc=0.5#2
  \hbox to #1{%
    \pdfliteral{ 
      q []0 d 
      1 J %  set line cap to rounded ends
      \strip@pt\@tempdimb\space w \strip@pt\@tempdimc\space 0 m 
      \strip@pt\@tempdima\space 0 l S Q }}}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}
x\mathrule{60bp}{2bp}x

x$\rule{60bp}{2bp}$x
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just to check: I assume this will work for `pdflatex` and `lualatex`, but not for plain `latex`.

Comment: That's a great start.  But I'm thinking you forgot to shave the rule width off the length of the `\mathrule`, when you added the rounded ends.  Am I just seeing it wrong?

Comment: add a `\ifpdf` and then use `\special` instead of `\pdfliteral` and the corresponfing PostScript function names. Pretty easy to realize.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: pdftex uses linecap=0. linecap=1 has the same line length than linecap=2. You can substract half the linewidth from the beginning and the end of the line and it will be the same.

Comment: Just for clarification, this does not take an optional argument, though a `\raisebox` could fix that, I suppose.

Comment: I also note that `\mathrule{60bp}{1bp}x\par$\rule{60bp}{1bp}$x` produces vastly different behavior among the two forms, as does `x\mathrule{60bp}{1bp}x\par x$\rule{60bp}{1bp}$x`

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: You have to put it into a horizontal box

Comment: The thing I really like about your solution is that it has no rendering artifacts, unlike any other solution that overlays an assortment of glyphs.

Answer (score 11):

I am posting this as the final result of taking Herbert's solution where I wanted it, which is a drop in replacement for `\rule` that provides rounded line caps.  Herbert deserves the credit and will get the points, but others (like me) might wish to see/use this more seamless drop-in for `\rule`.

Herbert's solution needed to be placed into an hbox, as he allowed, but it needed substantially more adjustments, as well.  The horizontal and vertical kernings were offset relative to that box, the vertical alignment of the rounded rule differed from that of a `\rule`, just to name a few.

**EDIT: I've also taken the initiative to force `\mathrule` to make a rule with the rounded endcaps on side/side or else the  top/bottom, depending on which dimension is larger, such that**

```
\mathrule{2ex}{2ex}
\mathrule{3ex}{2ex}
\mathrule{2ex}{3ex}
```

**gives**

[image]

In my MWE below, I put the final result through the paces of placing the `\mathrule` on a line by itself, placing it amongst text, stacking it, as well as `\fbox`ing it, in all cases comparing to its equivalent `\rule`.  The `\mystery@factor` in this MWE was later resolved by Dan in his comment.  His correction is incorporated into the style file `roundrule.sty` that I present at the end of this answer.

```
\pdfcompresslevel=0 %%% to see how it works in the pdf code
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{stackengine}% Used for testing; not needed for \math(v)rule's
\parindent=0pt
\makeatletter

\newcommand\mathrule[3][0pt]{%
  \ifdim#2>#3\math@hrule[#1]{#2}{#3}\else\math@vrule[#1]{#2}{#3}\fi}

\newcommand\math@hrule[3][0pt]{%
  \gdef\mystery@factor{0.07}%
 \@tempdima=#3%
  \rule[#1]{0pt}{#3}% Needed to account for .5\@tempdima vertical offset of rounded rule
  \raisebox{.5\@tempdima+#1}{%
    \makebox[#2][l]{\kern-.5\@tempdima\@@mathrule{#2}{#3}}}%
}

\newcommand\math@vrule[3][0pt]{%
  \gdef\mystery@factor{0.0}%
 \@tempdima=#2%
  \rule[#1]{0pt}{#3}% Needed to account for .5\@tempdima vertical offset of rounded rule
  \raisebox{-.0\@tempdima+#1}{%
    \kern0.5\@tempdima%
    \rotatebox{90}{\kern-0.5\@tempdima\makebox[#3][l]{\@@mathrule{#3}{#2}}}%
    \kern0.5\@tempdima}%
}

\def\@@mathrule#1#2{%
  \@tempdimb=#2%
  \@tempdima=\dimexpr#1-\mystery@factor\@tempdimb%Why 0.07 for \math@hrule?
  \pdfliteral{%
    q []0 d %
    1 J %  set line cap to rounded ends
    \strip@pt\@tempdimb\space w \strip@pt\@tempdimb\space 0 m %
    \strip@pt\@tempdima\space 0 l S Q }}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\mathrule{60bp}{1bp}\par
\rule{60bp}{1bp}\par
x\mathrule[-1pt]{20bp}{1bp}x\mathrule{20bp}{1bp}x\par
x\rule[-1pt]{20bp}{1bp}x\rule{20bp}{1bp}x\par
\stackunder[2pt]{\rule{60bp}{3bp}}{\mathrule{60bp}{3bp}}\par
\fbox{\mathrule[-1ex]{4ex}{.5ex}}\fbox{\rule[-1ex]{4ex}{.5ex}}\par
\fbox{\mathrule[+1ex]{4ex}{.5ex}}\fbox{\rule[+1ex]{4ex}{.5ex}}\par
\clearpage
\mathrule{1bp}{60bp} \rule{1bp}{60bp}\par
x\mathrule[-1pt]{1bp}{20bp}x\mathrule{1bp}{20bp}x%
  \rule[-1pt]{1bp}{20bp}x\rule{1bp}{20bp}x\par
x\rule[-1pt]{1bp}{20bp}x\rule{1bp}{20bp}x\par
\stackunder[2pt]{\rule{3bp}{10bp}\mathrule{3bp}{10bp}}%
  {\mathrule{3bp}{10bp}\rule{3bp}{10bp}}\par
\fbox{\mathrule[-1ex]{.5ex}{4ex}}\fbox{\rule[-1ex]{.5ex}{4ex}}\par
\fbox{\mathrule[+1ex]{.5ex}{4ex}}\fbox{\rule[+1ex]{.5ex}{4ex}}\par
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

For those interested in an *ad hoc* package (and taking azetina's renaming suggestion since it functions outside of math mode), here is `roundrule.sty`, introducing the macro `\roundrule[]{}{}`.  And thanks to Dan for resolving and eliminating the mystery factor.  Of course, `\roundrule`s can be used in text mode without the use of dollar delimiters.  Feel free to `\let\rrule\roundrule` in your preamble, if you get tired of typing the long name.

EDITED to require package `calc` as well.

```
\ProvidesPackage{roundrule}
[2014/05/01 V1.01 Provides rules with rounded endcaps]
%
% THIS MATERIAL IS SUBJECT TO THE LaTeX Project Public License
%
% Special thanks to users Herbert and Prof. Dan Luecking at tex.stackexchange.com:
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161297/
%        is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-mathrule-rounded-endcaps
%
% V1.00 - initial release
% V1.01 - require package calc, which was omitted as an oversight.

\pdfcompresslevel=0 %%% to see how it works in the pdf code
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{calc}

\newcommand\roundrule[3][0pt]{%
  \ifdim#2>#3\round@hrule[#1]{#2}{#3}\else\round@vrule[#1]{#2}{#3}\fi}

\newcommand\round@hrule[3][0pt]{%
  \@tempdima=#3%
  \rule[#1]{0pt}{#3}% Needed to account for .5\@tempdima vertical offset of rounded rule
  \raisebox{.5\@tempdima+#1}{%
    \makebox[#2][l]{\kern-.5\@tempdima\@@roundrule{#2}{#3}}}%
}

\newcommand\round@vrule[3][0pt]{%
  \@tempdima=#2%
  \rule[#1]{0pt}{#3}% Needed to account for .5\@tempdima vertical offset of rounded rule
  \raisebox{-.0\@tempdima+#1}{%
    \kern0.5\@tempdima%
    \rotatebox{90}{\kern-0.5\@tempdima\makebox[#3][l]{\@@roundrule{#3}{#2}}}%
    \kern0.5\@tempdima}%
}

\def\@@roundrule#1#2{%
  \@tempdima=#1%
  \@tempdimb=#2%
  \@tempdima=0.996264\@tempdima% LaTeX to PDF point conversion (72/72.27)
  \@tempdimb=0.996264\@tempdimb% LaTeX to PDF point conversion (72/72.27)
  \pdfliteral{%
    q []0 d %
    1 J %  set line cap to rounded ends
    \strip@pt\@tempdimb\space w \strip@pt\@tempdimb\space 0 m %
    \strip@pt\@tempdima\space 0 l S Q }}

\endinput
```

Comment: Its as easy as a find and replace on the text editor. I would go for the `\roundrule`

Comment: @azetina I feel a nudge.  While naming the package `roundrule`, do you think the macro should be `\roundrule` or `\rrule`?

Comment: hmmmm??? I would say `\rrule` is more practical but `\roundrule` says it all. Honestly, its just taste and consideration for compatibility cases. Is `\rrule` defined elsewhere?

Comment: @azetina I already checked.  `\rrule` shows up nowhere on this website.  Perhaps I'll leave it `\roundrule` and let the user employ a `\let\rrule\roundrule`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Could the mystery factor be needed because TeX works with `pt`, which is 1/72.27 inch, while in PDF the default unit is 1/72 inch? I removed the mystery factor calculations, but added `\@tempdima=0.996264\@tempdima` and `\@tempdimb=0.996264\@tempdimb` to `\@@mathrule` (0.996264 = 72/72.27). It seemed to work just fine for both horizontal and vertical rules: lengths matched within 1pixel at 1600% magnification.

Comment: @Dan Thanks for that insight!  It rings of truth, and is much better than a mystery factor.  I'll have a look.