# Problem with symbol

Tags: symbols

I am trying to write a math paper, and I need to write the following symbol:

`$\overline{\underline{X}}$`

Is there any package that already contains it?

Comment: I'm not sure whether a macro is defined by some package for that, but you can always define your own, e.g.: `\newcommand\ovunderline[1]{\overline{\underline{#1}}}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! What is the notation supposed to represent?

Comment: Do you mean an `X` with bars above and below close to it, like what is sometimes found for representing Roman numerals?

Comment: Does [this question](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/romanbar) help you?

Comment: We are doing sets and relations between them, and the professor usually writes a capital X with bars connecting the two upper extremities together, and the two lower ones as well. What I do not like about this one is the space between the lines and the letter, I would like to eliminate that

Comment: @user2287089 That's a device some people use on the blackboard, to avoid confusion with other symbols. Is it used also in print?

Comment: Running with what @egreg has already said, there are many times when printed notation is different from blackboard notation.  Take for example the difference between `\mathbf` and `\mathbb`; I (almost) always see `bf` (bold face) in print, whereas I *always* see `bb` (blackboard) on, well, the blackboard.  On the board it's about what is convenient to write; on paper it's about what is convenient to read.

Comment: @SeanAllred you would? For number sets I'd definitely expect to see double struck letters (and never bold) for N, Z, Q etc.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I suppose it's an isolated experience then---I've never seen anything that deviates too far from what I said.  The one or two times I *did* see `\mathbb` for the number sets, it looked *awful* odd to me.  Maybe I'm just not reading enough. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, thanks to Keba I found the solution. You can use the romanbar package, which puts bars on top and bottom of a letter, without leaving a gap.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{romanbar}
\begin{document}
\Romanbar{X}
\end{document}
```

This generates:

[image: Romanbar]

Thanks to everyone for their help!!!

Answer (score 4):

The `\overline{\underline{}}` mentioned by Jubobs is easier, if you are happy with that look, unless you wanted to tweak the settings I mention below, or if you want rounded caps on your over/under rules.  If you wanted this done on text, rather than math variables, then removing the `$` from my definitions will accomplish that.

You can perform an over/understack, as shown here.  The rule thickness is set to 0.33pt and can be changed.  The offset above and below is set to 1pt and can be changed.

The commented out code includes a cute package located at [Is there such a thing as a `\mathrule`? (rounded endcaps)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161297/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-mathrule-rounded-endcaps/161309#161309), which gives rules a round endcap, rather than a chopped off norm of `\rule`.  The image I show includes both versions

```
\documentclass{article}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161297/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-mathrule-rounded-endcaps/161309#161309
%\usepackage{roundrule}
%\let\rrule\roundrule
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\overunderline#1{%
\setbox0=\hbox{$#1$}%
  \stackon[1pt]{\stackunder[1pt]{$#1$}{\rule{\wd0}{.33pt}}}{\rule{\wd0}{.33pt}}%
}
%\def\roverunderline#1{%
%\setbox0=\hbox{$#1$}%
%  \stackon[1pt]{\stackunder[1pt]{$#1$}{\rrule{\wd0}{.33pt}}}{\rrule{\wd0}{.33pt}}%
%}
%\parskip 1ex
\begin{document}
$x\overunderline{x}\overunderline{f}\overunderline{G}y$\par
%$x\roverunderline{x}\roverunderline{f}\roverunderline{G}y$
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

EDIT:  Seeing a comment of the OP, I offer this additional solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\dbar#1{%
\setbox0=\hbox{#1}%
  \def\stackalignment{r}\stackon[-.25pt]{%
    \def\stackalignment{l}\stackunder[-.3pt]{%
      $#1$}{\rule{.95\wd0}{.33pt}}}{\rule{.95\wd0}{.33pt}}%
}
\begin{document}
\dbar X \dbar Y \dbar R
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here are non-italic versions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\def\dbar#1{%
\setbox0=\hbox{#1}%
  \stackon[-.25pt]{\stackunder[-.3pt]{#1}{\rule{.95\wd0}{.33pt}}}{\rule{.95\wd0}{.33pt}}%
}
\begin{document}
\dbar X \dbar Y \dbar R
\end{document}
```

[image]