# \varamalg and \varcoprod operators for disjoint union

Tags: math-operators

For the disjoint union, I don't like `\amalg` and `\coprod` very much. So, I did all my best to create a `\varamalg` with this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}

\newcommand{\varamalg}{\sqcup\hspace{-1.085em}\raisebox{-.195em}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{37}{$\smallsetminus$}}}

\begin{document}

$A\varamalg B=A\cup B$

\end{document}
```

And I get:

[image]

Well, not bad for me. I used `\smallsetminus` because the ends are rounded.

But now, I'm not able to create `\varcoprod`. Could you help me?

Comment: Obtain `roundrule.sty` at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161297/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-mathrule-rounded-endcaps/161309#161309

Comment: So by `\varcoprod` you're just after an operator-type `\varamalg`? If not, could you explain more what `\varcoprod` should look like, and how you plan on using it?