# \mapstochar without the protuberance on the right side (i.e., a rounded vertical bar)

Tags: symbols

The `\mapstochar` character is a vertical bar, with borders slightly rounded and a protuberance on its right-side, in the middle:

[image]

I'm trying to get the same symbol, *but without the protuberance on the right-side*.

I have been through the The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List, looked up the definition of `\mapstochar` (`\mathchar"3237`), searched this website high and low (for instance, [Creating a smaller vertical bar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174746/creating-a-smaller-vertical-bar) ), but could not find any way of getting a *rounded* vertical bar.

Comment: tikz? or do you need a font glyph

Comment: Either is fine, really.

Answer (score 2):

Picture mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\smallbar}{}{%
  \mathrel{\mathpalette\smallbar@\relax}%
}

\newcommand{\current@math@font}[1]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle\textfont\else
  \ifx#1\textstyle\textfont\else
  \ifx#1\scriptstyle\scriptfont\else
  \scriptscriptfont\fi\fi\fi
}
\newcommand{\smallbar@factor}[1]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle 1.135\else
  \ifx#1\textstyle 1.128\else
  \ifx#1\scriptstyle 1.09\else
  1.06\fi\fi\fi
}

\newcommand{\smallbar@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\mapstochar$}%
  \dimen0=\smallbar@factor{#1}\ht\z@
  \dimen2=\dimeval{2\fontdimen22\current@math@font{#1} 2 - \dimen0}%
  \mbox{%
    $\m@th#1\mkern1mu
    \begin{picture}(0,\dimen0)
    \roundcap
    \linethickness{\fontdimen8\current@math@font{#1}3}
    \Line(0,\dimen2)(0,\dimen0)
    \end{picture}%
    \mkern1mu$%
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\mapstochar\,\smallbar$
$\scriptstyle\mapstochar\,\smallbar$
$\scriptscriptstyle\mapstochar\,\smallbar$


\end{document}
```

[image]