# How to produce U+22F2 (⋲)?

Tags: symbols

Apparently `Latin Modern Roman` does not include it. I don't find it in the math symbols, either. I guess I could define a command changing to [some other font](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/22f2/fontsupport.htm) for it, but I suspect there's a better way and I just didn't look in the right place yet?

Edit:

One possible solution is the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[math-style=TeX]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont
[    Extension = .otf,
     BoldFont = *bold,
]{xits-math}
\begin{document}
$\disin$
\end{document}
```

But apparently that will change the font for all math environments, which I am a bit hesitant to do.

Comment: I’m pretty sure this has already been asked

Comment: @egreg Well, maybe, but I didn't find a question. I now found it included in the unicode-math package, but still need to find a font for it, and I wonder whether loading unicode-math would make changes to other things done via math mode.

Comment: @egreg This one? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174989/create-longer-arrows/175009#175009

Comment: it is not a duplicate since this one is based on an issue with `unicode-math` and that other one does not address it, even the title is out of context, not to mention the tags on it.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a unicode glyph range for a specific font, say

```
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range = {"22F2-"22F2,}]{STIX Two Math}
```

this way only U+22F2 will be replaced by the glyph inside STIX Two Math.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
% \let\latinencoding\relax

\usepackage[math-style = upright]{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range = {"22F2-"22F2,}]{STIX Two Math}

\begin{document}

text1

\( \disin text2 \)

\end{document}
```

producing

[image]