# Looking for some special types of parentheses

Tags: fonts, symbols

I am looking for some parentheses symbols which I present here. It will be better if we can stretch these symbol to have large parentheses. If these symbols are able to be constructed manually, please share your codes. 
Thanks

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Please see [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/175432) for some brackets and provide an MWE with those.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100966/defining-scalable-white-curly-brackets-and-and

Comment: Have you checked The Comprehensive LaTeX Symbol List yet?

Comment: It will be better if we can use these symbols without implementing unicode math. Indeed, I knew many of them can be provided through unicode math package.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't access these symbols from a Unicode font, but you can see them on screen, you could grab them in some form and then include them as a graphic.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\lbrackopen}{%
    \raisebox{-.6ex}{%
         \includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{lbrackopen}%
    }%
}
\begin{document}

I could use [this] left bracket or \lbrackopen this] one.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the "open" bracket is a little too high.  to match the others, it should be vertically centered around the math axis.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I agree - Is there a systematic way to do that other than just guessing?

Comment: well, treating a single glyph as an operator (`\qopname` or something like that -- i'm away from all tex files until next week) would center it vertically on the math axis, and it could then be declared as `\mathopen`.  that's really a goshawful, ridiculous kludge!  but the "best" i can conjure up at the moment.

Comment: Can this approach be used in math mode enviroment ?

Comment: It sounds like @barbarabeeton knows how to set this up for math mode. Other than putting `\ensuremath{}` into the command, I don't know.

Comment: @Elias -- an operator *must* be used in math mode.  it isn't defined for use in text.  (using `\ensuremath{}` artificially provides math mode within text, but that just conceals the fact, and can make it hard to find all the math bits in a document when circumstances make that necessary.)  `amsmath` provides facilities for specifying that something is an operator more easily than "basic" latex.