# Square-bracket-like symbol for typesetting intervals used by Bourbaki

Tags: math-mode, symbols

It is common in French to use square brackets to write all kinds of intervals, like: $[0, 1]$, $]0,1[$, $[0,1[$, $]0,1]$, see [Intervalle (mathématiques)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intervalle_(math%C3%A9matiques)).

However, this seems to be a mistake. If you look, for example, in texts of Bourbaki, the symbols they used were not square brackets, and they reminded a bit `\lgroup` and `\rgroup`, see the screenshots.

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

What is the right LaTeX symbol to use for typesetting intervals in this notation?

My understanding was that the symbol must be somewhat standard, but some comments make me think it could be not. Was it standard, or was it used exclusively by Bourbaki?

Comment: Possibly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175407/are-there-hexagon-brackets-in-latex?rq=1

Comment: Why is the use of brackets for intervals a mistake, if this is the current convention? [Unless you are typesetting a historic document with the conventions used then] The interval brackets by Bourbaki seem to be between ( and [ and are hard to distinguish. For most mathematicians, Bourbaki is not a bible to be taken literally but another step towards modern mathematics

Comment: @gernot, I did not check other texts of the same period as the Bourbaki, do you think the others used square brackets? I suspect that the correct symbol was the one used by Bourbaki, and the "current convention" could be just laziness, or symplicity, or difficulty with finding the correct symbol.

Comment: Your question is not clear, are you asking what the best practice for typesetting intervals is or how to replicate the symbols used by Bourbaki? If it's the first, @gernot is right.

Comment: @DG', i am looking for the symbol used in the snapshots. I will add an extra question.

Comment: @gernot, in other words, i suspected that the convention is the same, only the square brackets is not the right symbol. (Who would care to look for the one when writing a Wikipedia article if square brackets look almost the same?)

Comment: @Alexey I still don't understand what you are aiming at. If for some reason you want/have to use exactly the same notation as Bourbaki did, then the question is how to produce the historic symbols. If you write a contemporary math text, then take your favorite textbook and write the intervals as they do there. Inventing one's own notation or insisting on an unusual histoic notation is probably not the best idea.

Comment: @gernot, that some usage is currently deemed contemporary is not a sufficient reason to adopt it. To discard some usage as "historical" it needs to be explained why some other is better. If i try to take "my favourite textbook", there is a non-zero chance it was published long time ago. I see no reason to change mathematical notation every 50 years or so, unless a truly better notation is proposed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The symbols are available in some Unicode math fonts, namely as

U+2997 LEFT BLACK TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET ⦗
U+2998 RIGHT BLACK TORTOISE SHELL BRACKET ⦘

Not scaling, I'm afraid.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\begin{document}

$\lblkbrbrak a,b\rblkbrbrak$

$\mathopen\rblkbrbrak a,b\mathclose\lblkbrbrak$

$⦗a,b⦘$

$\mathopen⦘a,b\mathclose⦗$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Importing the symbols when the math font lacks them is easy with `unicode-math`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[range={\rblkbrbrak,\lblkbrbrak}]
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}[range={}]% to reset the math parameters

\begin{document}

$\lblkbrbrak a,b\rblkbrbrak$

$\mathopen\rblkbrbrak a,b\mathclose\lblkbrbrak$

$⦗a,b⦘$

$\mathopen⦘a,b\mathclose⦗$

\end{document}
```

[image]

For `pdflatex` it's a bit harder.

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix2}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{stixsymbols2}{LS1}{stix2frak}{m}{n}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\lblkbrbrak}{\mathopen} {stixsymbols2}{"36}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rblkbrbrak}{\mathclose}{stixsymbols2}{"37}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2997}{\lblkbrbrak}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2998}{\rblkbrbrak}

\begin{document}

$\lblkbrbrak a,b\rblkbrbrak$

$\mathopen\rblkbrbrak a,b\mathclose\lblkbrbrak$

$⦗a,b⦘$

$\mathopen⦘a,b\mathclose⦗$

\end{document}
```

Here I add also the nonthick versions (they're extensible). For `unicode-math` it's similar to the above, just with different names.

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS1}{stix2}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{stixsymbols2}{LS1}{stix2frak}{m}{n}

\DeclareFontEncoding{LS2}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{LS2}{stix2}{m}{n}

\DeclareSymbolFont{stixlargesymbols}  {LS2}{stix2ex}   {m} {n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\lblkbrbrak}{\mathopen} {stixsymbols2}{"36}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\rblkbrbrak}{\mathclose}{stixsymbols2}{"37}

\DeclareMathDelimiter{\lbrbrak}{\mathopen} {stixlargesymbols}{"EE}{stixlargesymbols}{"14}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{\rbrbrak}{\mathclose}{stixlargesymbols}{"EF}{stixlargesymbols}{"15}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2997}{\lblkbrbrak}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2998}{\rblkbrbrak}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2772}{\lbrbrak}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{2773}{\rbrbrak}

\begin{document}

$\lblkbrbrak a,b\rblkbrbrak$

$\mathopen\rblkbrbrak a,b\mathclose\lblkbrbrak$

$⦗a,b⦘$

$\mathopen⦘a,b\mathclose⦗$

$\lbrbrak a,b\rbrbrak$

$\mathopen\rbrbrak a,b\mathclose\lbrbrak$

$❲a,b❳$

$\mathopen❳a,b\mathclose❲$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Scaling should be possible, possibly by chopping the symbol in two and adding a line of the right width between the top and bottom parts. Take it as a challenge.

Comment: @Gaussler How does one chop up a symbol in two and perform this operation you mention? Could I ask you to furnish more details?

Comment: @ΑΘΩ One can do magic by using boxes to hide parts of the symbol. Such things are always possible in TeX. However, to do it in practise and in an efficient way requires a TeX guru, which I’m not. I suggest to make it into an actual question and hope that egreg answers.

Comment: @egreg Sir, I've noticed you have quite expert knowledge of LaTeX. Could I interest you in a question (concerning typesetting a special type of character) which didn't receive any answers on this forum?

Comment: Could you suggest please how to use these symbols without replacing the math font? I saw in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/331899) how to use plain tortoise shell brackets, but i wasn't able to adapt the answer to **black** tortoise shell brackets because they are not defined in the same way in [`stix.sty`](https://github.com/stipub/stixfonts/blob/master/archive/STIXv1.1.1/Fonts/stix-tds/tex/latex/stix/stix.sty).

Comment: @Alexey With `pdflatex` or `unicode-math`?

Comment: I would prefer a universal solution for PDFLaTeX and XeLaTeX. I am not using `unicode-math` currently, but would be interested to learn more about it.

Comment: @Alexey I added the code for both worlds.

Comment: @egreg: I'd like to try this but with`\lbrbrak` and `\rbrbrak` i.e., not the thick black versions. So: (1) How did you derive `"36` and `"37` from these characters Unicode numbers `2997` and `2998`? (2) What should I use instead of `stix2frak` in `\DeclareSymbolFont{stixsymbols2}{LS1}{stix2frak}{m}{n}`?

Comment: @murray I looked for the symbols in `stix2.sty`.

Comment: @murray I added the code.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for adding the code, although I understood exactly what to do as soon as I followe`d your suggestion to look in `stix2.sty`. (Before, I had looked only at `stix2.pdf`, from `texdoc stix2`, and saw there only the Unicode numbers.)

Comment: One can use the NewCM fonts to have the style of the brackets match LM. https://imgur.com/a/2qmkyKV