# On the appropriate method to type a particular type of obtuse brackets as well as ligatures for interiors (in topology)

Tags: symbols, typography

Greetings to the users of this forum!

One of the main purposes to which I use LaTeX is to typeset mathematical texts and I personally tend to be very particular about various styles of notation. For two of the methods of notation I am quite fond of I was not able to find so far any way to implement them in LaTeX, so I would like to enquire as to whether they are feasible in LaTeX and if so precisely how:

1. A special type of brackets whose horizontal arms are not perfectly horizontal and actually make an *obtuse* angle with the vertical side. A picture is going to be far more illustrative, so may I attach here an image from the *Set Theory* of Bourbaki, where I believe they first introduce this notation for intervals with respect to general order relations:

[image]

2. A special round ligature symbol useful in denoting interiors of subsets (of a given topological space) given by complicated expressions. I am explicitly referring to the following:

[image]

the curved horizontal brace-like ligature symbol (which spans the entire breadth of the intersection of *A* and *B*) being the entity I am interested in. The second image was taken from the first volume of *General Topology* of Bourbaki.

As a remark, both of the Bourbaki editions referenced above are relatively new so I would imagine they are fully typeset in LaTeX, which would of course stand to mean that a way of implementing these symbols certainly exists (although it might be somewhat obscure).

I am eagerly awaiting for any advice or opinions from the experts! In advance may I thank you for your time and good-will.

Comment: For the first question see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/573956/82917

Comment: @campa Thank you sir! That was precisely what I was looking for (the sole downside being that the bracket symbols in question don't seem to be scalable).