# Slash resembling "circled division slash"

Tags: math-mode, stmaryrd

The package [`stmaryrd`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/stmaryrd) defines two symbols `\varoslash` and `\varobslash` which resemble the "circled division slash" ⊘ and an similar backslash.

However, when mixing these circled slashes and regular slashes `/`, `\`, the differences in size and angle makes the formulas look weird.

What is the easiest way for me to get slashes which are similar to these slashes in their size and angle, but don't have the circle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get round caps using picture mode:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stmaryrd,pict2e,picture}

\newcommand{\varbslash}{%
  \mathbin{\mathpalette\pictvarbslash\relax}%
}

\newcommand{\pictvarbslash}[2]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{%
    \sbox0{$#1\varobslash$}\dimen0=.55\wd0
    \begin{picture}(\dimen0,\dimen0)
    \roundcap
    \put(0,\dimen0){\line(1,-1){\dimen0}}
    \end{picture}%
  }}%
}

\begin{document}
$\varobslash\varbslash_{\varobslash\varbslash}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's an expanded version with `\varslash`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stmaryrd,pict2e,picture}

\newcommand{\varslash}{%
  \mathbin{\mathpalette\pictslash{{0}{1}}}%
}
\newcommand{\varbslash}{%
  \mathbin{\mathpalette\pictslash{{1}{-1}}}%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\pictslash}[2]{%
  \vcenter{\hbox{%
    \sbox0{$\m@th#1\varobslash$}\dimen0=.55\wd0
    \pictslash@aux#2%
  }}%
}
\newcommand{\pictslash@aux}[2]{%
    \begin{picture}(\dimen0,\dimen0)
    \roundcap
    \put(0,#1\dimen0){\line(1,#2){\dimen0}}
    \end{picture}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\varobslash\varbslash_{\varobslash\varbslash}$

$\varoslash\varslash_{\varoslash\varslash}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another variant where the new symbols occupy the same space as the corresponding circled ones:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stmaryrd,pict2e,picture}

\newcommand{\varslash}{%
  \mathbin{\mathpalette\pictslash{{0}{1}}}%
}
\newcommand{\varbslash}{%
  \mathbin{\mathpalette\pictslash{{1}{-1}}}%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\pictslash}[2]{%
  \vcenter{%
    \sbox0{$\m@th#1\varobslash$}\dimen0=.55\wd0
    \hbox to\wd 0{%
      \hfil\pictslash@aux#2\hfil
    }%
  }%
}
\newcommand{\pictslash@aux}[2]{%
    \begin{picture}(\dimen0,\dimen0)
    \roundcap
    \put(0,#1\dimen0){\line(1,#2){\dimen0}}
    \end{picture}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$\varobslash\varobslash_{\varobslash\varobslash}$

$\varobslash\varbslash_{\varobslash\varbslash}$

$\varoslash\varslash_{\varoslash\varslash}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing the slash shouldn't be too different--moving the origin back to 0, changing the line's direction vector. However, could you perhaps explain what you're using the original, circled character for? And what the meaning of the variables `dimen0` and `wd0` are?

Comment: And is there, using those variables, some way I can make `varslash` and `varbslash`'s bounding boxes be the same as those for `varoslash` and `varobslash`--i.e. make them take up as much space without making the actual characters bigger?

Comment: I measure the diameter of `\varobslash` which is available as `\wd0` (because it was in box register 0); then the scratch length parameter `\dimen0` is set to 55% of the width. I'll add also the variant for the increased space.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what math class you would like these symbols to be, so I did not assign that.  But you could add `\mathbin`, `\mathop`, etc. to the definition to suit.

I have EDITED the answer to let them operate inside of sub/super-scripts.

I have RE-EDITED to make the rules rounded, using my `roundrule.sty` package found only at [Is there such a thing as a `\mathrule`? (rounded endcaps)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161297/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-mathrule-rounded-endcaps/161309#161309), which provides a drop-in replacement for `\rule` called `\roundrule`, giving rounded end-caps.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stmaryrd,graphicx,scalerel,roundrule}
\def\varslash{\ThisStyle{\rotatebox{48}{\roundrule{1.4\LMex}{.1\LMex}}}}
\def\varbslash{\ThisStyle{\rotatebox[origin=right]{-48}{\roundrule{1.4\LMex}{.1\LMex}}}}
\begin{document}
${\varoslash} {\varslash} {\varobslash} {\varbslash}$\par
\LARGE${\varoslash} {\varslash} {\varobslash} {\varbslash}$\par
$x_{{\varoslash} {\varslash} {\varobslash} {\varbslash}}$\par
\end{document}
```

[image]