# Typesetting a nested \lrcorner?

Tags: symbols

I'd like to create the symbol below, with a "nested" `\lrcorner`. How is this possible?

[image]

Comment: How are you going to use this? You can draw it with `picture` (loading `pict2e` package).

Comment: @Manuel I want to use this symbol for homotopy pullbacks in commutative diagrams.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution with the `\stackinset` command, from `stackengine`:

```
\documentclass[11pt, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\Lrcorner{\mathclose{\ensurestackMath{\stackinset{l}{0.018em}{t}{0.01em}{\scriptstyle\lrcorner} {\lrcorner}}}}

\begin{document}

$ \Lrcorner $

\end{document}
```

[image]

[Steven B. Segletes edit] follows:

```
\documentclass[11pt, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand\Lrcorner{\mathclose{\ensurestackMath{\stackinset{l}{0.018em}{t}{0.01em}{\ooalign{$\scriptstyle\lrcorner$\cr\raisebox{-.1pt}{\kern.1pt$\scriptstyle\lrcorner$}}} {\lrcorner}}}}

\begin{document}

$ \Lrcorner $

\end{document}
```

[image]

[Bernard edit]
This code gives both `\lrcorners` and `\ulcorners`. They have exactly the  same line thickness:

```
\documentclass[11pt, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
\usepackage{stackengine} 
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newcommand\LRcorner{\mathclose{\stackinset{l}{0.004em}{t}{-0.09em}{\rlap{\clipbox{0pt -0.3pt 0.15em 0pt}{$\lrcorner $}}\hspace{-0.093em}\clipbox{0pt 0.09em 0pt 0pt}{$\lrcorner $}}{$\lrcorner $}}}
\newcommand\ULcorner{\mathopen{\stackinset{r}{0.005em}{t}{0.1em}{\rlap{\clipbox{0pt 0pt 0pt 0.1em}{$\ulcorner $}}\hspace{0.07em}\raisebox{-0.1em}{\clipbox{0.175em 0pt 0pt 0pt}{$\ulcorner $}}}{$ \ulcorner $}}}

\begin{document}

 $ \ulcorner    \ULcorner  \mathrm B   \LRcorner  \lrcorner  $ 

   \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! How is it possible to make both symbols of the same thickness?

Comment: I just knew @Arrow was going to ask that.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes How come? :D

Comment: I'm afraid you should design a new character using TikZ or pstricks…

Comment: @Arrow Because I've used Bernard's trick enough times to have heard that same reply often.  I have edited Bernard's answer to give you another possibility.

Comment: @Steven D. Segletes: It's been some time I'm looking forward to study the `\ooalign` command… I tried with `\boldsymbol` biut there sems to be no boldversion. Maybe with some cropping trick.

Comment: Before you posted, I was playing around with a cropping trick.  But the natural crop crops off the rounded ends.  Cropping out the middle would be significantly more tedious.

Comment: My idea was to crop twice: once to keep a shorter vertical line with a rounded end, once to keep a horizontal one, and adjust all this stuff with `\stackinset`. Tedious, as you say…

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes thank you very much for the edited solution. Is it possible to make the each `lrcorner` symbol a bit thinner and have the vertical spacing and horizontal spacing between them the same?

Comment: I'd upvote you twice, if I could.  Nice clipbox edit.

Comment: @Steven B. Segletes: Thanks. I've upvoted your fine round rule solution. You'll note the corner of the smaller lrcorner is not rounded. I wondered whether such a rounded element exists somewhere?

Comment: OR... you could go clip-crazy and perform a double clip to remove the middle of each line segment, rather than the ends.

Comment: That' would be fun!

Comment: @Bernard your last edit was perfect! Any change you could post an analogous command for `ulcorner`? I tried tweaking with it for a while but only got ugly things..

Comment: @Arrow: I'll do it if no one else has posted, but later – I don't have time at the moment.

Comment: @Arrow: I've just updated my answer to incorporate  `\ULcorner`.

Answer (score 4):

This answer uses the `roundrule` package, found exclusively at the end of this answer: [Is there such a thing as a `\mathrule`? (rounded endcaps)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161297/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-mathrule-rounded-endcaps/161309#161309).  It provides three parameters to tweak the design:

1. `\LRthk` is the rule thickness;
2. `\LRwd` is the width of the symbol (not counting the 1pt buffer on both sides); and
3. `\LRfrac` is the relative size of the small corner to the large corner.

Here is the MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{roundrule}
\usepackage{stackengine,amssymb}
\newlength\LRthk
\newlength\LRwd
\LRthk=.08ex\relax
\LRwd=.91ex\relax
\def\LRfrac{.75}
\def\Bcorner{\roundrule[-\LRfrac\LRthk]{\LRwd}{\LRthk}\kern-\LRthk%
  \roundrule[-\LRfrac\LRthk]{\LRthk}{\LRwd}}
\def\Lcorner{\roundrule[-\LRfrac\LRthk]{\LRfrac\LRwd}{\LRthk}\kern-\LRthk%
  \roundrule[-\LRfrac\LRthk]{\LRthk}{\LRfrac\LRwd}}
\newcommand\LRcorner{%
  \mathclose{\kern1pt\stackinset{l}{}{t}{}{\Lcorner}{\Bcorner}\kern1pt}}
\begin{document}
$ \lrcorner\LRcorner x$
\end{document}
```

[image]