# Show postscript point versus Anglo-Saxon point

Tags: postscript, points

I am doing a practical job comparing the postscript point (1/72) with the Anglo-Saxon point (1/72.27).
I need help to be able to show the difference in size in a character (it is indistinct of which).
The idea is to show the difference not with a rule, but with two overlapping characters (one on top of the other).
Thanks for the help

Comment: Not that it answers your question, but the issue of 1/72 vs. 1/72.27 came up in this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161297/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-mathrule-rounded-endcaps/161309#161309.  I was calling it `\mystery@factor` before Dan figured out what it was.

Answer (score 1):

The visual difference is small:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}

\newlength\charheight

\begin{document}
\settoheight\charheight{\Huge X}
\setlength\charheight{\charheight*\ratio{72.27pt}{72pt}}

pt$\rightarrow$\scalebox{10}{\Huge X\resizebox{!}{\charheight}{X}}$\leftarrow$bp
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution (the difference is very small...).

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=0mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0]
  \begin{scope}[blend group=difference]
    \node[font=\fontsize{52pt}{52pt}\selectfont]{A};
    \node[font=\fontsize{52bp}{52bp}\selectfont,text=white]{A};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a south west anchored variant:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=0mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[inner sep=0]
  \begin{scope}[blend group=difference]
    \node[anchor=south west,font=\fontsize{52pt}{52pt}\selectfont]{A};
    \node[anchor=south west,font=\fontsize{52bp}{52bp}\selectfont,text=white]{A};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Paul, your example is what I need, but the characters should not be centered, but anchored at a point equivalent to 0 of an x ​​and y coordinate, to correctly dimension the difference. Is it possible with is code?

Comment: @ImagoMundi You can add the `anchor=south east` key to each node...

Comment: Thanks Paul, it's exactly what I was looking for.
My practical work is based on showing that this small difference added to 800,000 characters (for example a 320-page book) plus the efficiency of the TeX engine in typographical calculations, make a big difference.

Answer (score 0):

If I compile

```
\font\PT=ptmr at 1000pt
\font\BP=ptmr at 1000bp

\setbox0=\hbox{\PT A}\showthe\ht0
\setbox0=\hbox{\BP A}\showthe\ht0

\bye
```

I get on the console

```
> 673.00034pt.
l.4 \setbox0=\hbox{\PT A}\showthe\ht0

? 
> 675.52408pt.
l.5 \setbox0=\hbox{\BP A}\showthe\ht0

?
```

which means that the difference in height is about 2.5pt, less than one 1mm. At 100pt/100bp, the difference is less than 0.1mm.

You're not going to see any difference at standard sizes (and TeX *doesn't* load fonts at different sizes if the gap is very small).

Here's the picture I get by printing a black 1000bp A under a red 1000pt A, at 2400% (just the top).

[image]

At 100% magnification on a Retina display,

[image]