# Style of the plus symbol

Tags: symbols

[image]
How do we make it like this: (Rounded corners and more thinner)
........[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tgheros}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{mathastext}
%
\makeatletter
\mathchardef\standardplus=\mathcode`+
\DeclareRobustCommand{\tauyecoplus}{%
\mathbin{\mathpalette\tauyeco@plus\relax}%
}
\newcommand{\tauyeco@plus}[2]{
\raisebox{-0.1\height}{\scalebox{1.4}{\hspace{-0.1mm}$\m@th#1\standardplus$}}%
}
\begingroup\lccode`~=`+ \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\tauyecoplus
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`+="8000 }
\makeatother
%
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[+\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe find another font?

Comment: @Gaussler I tried suggesting that  on the previous 4 identical questions

Comment: @DavidCarlisle But this font is just oh so very beautiful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did with `\usepackage{MnSymbol}`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tgheros}
\usepackage{mathastext}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
%
\makeatletter
\mathchardef\standardplus=\mathcode`+
\DeclareRobustCommand{\tauyecoplus}{%
  \mathbin{\mathpalette\tauyeco@plus\relax}%
}
\newcommand{\tauyeco@plus}[2]{
  \raisebox{-0.05\height}{\scalebox{1.4}{\hspace{-0.1mm}$\m@th#1\standardplus$}}%
}
\begingroup\lccode`~=`+ \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\tauyecoplus
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`+="8000 }
\makeatother
%
\begin{document}
$$+$$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have conformed the scale and position of the macro `\+` to your redefined `+`.  Of course, it can be tuned by changing the dimensions specified, since it is composed by overlaying two "round rules", as defined in the `roundrule` package found only here: [Is there such a thing as a `\mathrule`? (rounded endcaps)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161297/is-there-such-a-thing-as-a-mathrule-rounded-endcaps/161309#161309).  Works as is in pdflatex.  The dimensions would need to be adjustment in lualatex.  Doesn't work in xelatex.

The MWE shows the result in all math styles.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tgheros}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{mathastext}
%
\makeatletter
\mathchardef\standardplus=\mathcode`+
\DeclareRobustCommand{\tauyecoplus}{%
\mathbin{\mathpalette\tauyeco@plus\relax}%
}
\newcommand{\tauyeco@plus}[2]{
\raisebox{-0.1\height}{\scalebox{1.4}{\hspace{-0.1mm}$\m@th#1\standardplus$}}%
}
\begingroup\lccode`~=`+ \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\tauyecoplus
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`+="8000 }
\makeatother
%
\usepackage{roundrule,stackengine,scalerel}
\renewcommand\scriptstyleScaleFactor{.83}
\renewcommand\scriptscriptstyleScaleFactor{.66}
\newcommand\+{\mathbin{\kern1pt\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{\roundrule[2.7\LMpt]{.8\LMpt}{6.5\LMpt}}%
  {\roundrule[2.7\LMpt]{6.5\LMpt}{.8\LMpt}}}}\kern1pt}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[{+}{\+}\quad\scriptstyle +\+\quad\scriptscriptstyle+\+\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This of course can be made the default plus, using the same `\mathcode` approach as the OP was using:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{roundrule,stackengine,scalerel}
\renewcommand\scriptstyleScaleFactor{.83}
\renewcommand\scriptscriptstyleScaleFactor{.66}
\newcommand\myplus{\mathbin{\kern1pt\ThisStyle{\ensurestackMath{%
  \stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{\roundrule[2.7\LMpt]{.8\LMpt}{6.5\LMpt}}%
  {\roundrule[2.7\LMpt]{6.5\LMpt}{.8\LMpt}}}}\kern1pt}}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tgheros}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{mathastext}
%
\makeatletter
\begingroup\lccode`~=`+ \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\myplus
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`+="8000 }
\makeatother
%
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\[a+b\quad\scriptstyle a+b\quad\scriptscriptstyle a+b\]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I made the compiler lualatex. But it gives an error when I write the code in overleaf.

Comment: @Pitaya88 I am sure overleaf knows nothing about `roundrule.sty`, unless you copied it over from the link I provided.

Comment: I'm sorry but I couldn't understand. I'm using overleaft, is it possible for me to open this code there?

Comment: Error is: `Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 
   
l.3 \renewcommand
               \scriptstyleScaleFactor{.83}
*** (cannot \read from terminal in nonstop modes)`

Comment: @Pitaya88 That error seems to be associated with not understanding the existence of the `scalerel` package.  Normally, `\usepackage{scalerel}` would be sufficient to trigger it's loading.  However, I do not use overleaf and so am of limited assistance on such things.

Comment: I understand, thank you for your help. @Steven B. Segletes