# Using Texas Instrument font with LaTeX

Tags: fonts

I would like to use a font similar to the one use on a Texas Instruments TI-30X calculator.

[image: calculator]

Is there a font like this?

Comment: there is a package for casio fonts. Is this close enough?

Comment: @samcarter If there is nothing better I can use it but I would like a font closer to the one used in the TI-30X.

Comment: You may find [this one](http://www.fontspace.com/30100flo/graph-35-pix) to be very close?

Comment: @AboAmmar Close but not perfect. `:-)`

Comment: Does this question [Mimicking a calculator inputs and screen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/290321/mimicking-a-calculator-inputs-and-screen) help?

Comment: These appear to be characters made with pixels in a 7x5 array. Try lcd package. There is an answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/394832

Comment: @DJP This seems to be really good! I'm at work now but 'll test it when I get home.